# Постоянное обновление переменной в фоне

Tags: python

Вопрос возможно глупый, но касается именно правильной реализации.

Есть 3 функции, которые работают с одними и теми же данными. Одна выполняется раз в 1 минуту, две раз в 10 минут. Сейчас это реализовано так, что каждая функция делает новый запрос к сайту и парсит данные заново.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом лучше будет реализовать следующую модель работы. Автоматически в фоне каждую минуту парсятся данные с сайта, а каждая функция при срабатывании берёт последние данные, которые были взяты с сайта.

Насколько я понимаю это постоянный процесс в фоне, которые подменивает переменную, а уже при вызове функций эта переменная передаётся им. Не совсем понятно как запустить этот постоянный процесс правильно.

Comment: Объединить в класс и хранить все в `self.variables`?

Comment: То есть, я делаю асинхронную функцию, которая выполняет парсинг каждую минуту и записывает всё в экземпляр класса, а этот экземпляр обновляется и при любом вызове использовать этот экземпляр или же всё это прописать методами класса?

Comment: Я бы лучше в какой-то легковесной БД такие данные хранил, чтобы не париться с потокобезопасностью. Ну, если данные не очень большие.